# Install mod page speed module on whm centos

Tags: apache, centos, whm, mod-pagespeed

Hi every one i am little bit confuse about to install mod page speed module because i am very new to doing this task first time.

Issue:- Where to install the mod page speed module.i have two cpanel so where to exact installation need to start first is WHM go daddy or regular cpanel for my site.

```
    1) WHM go daddy  
    2) regular cpanel for my site
```

I have the bellow configuration

```
    1) Operating System:CentOS 5
    2) Apache:- Server Version: Apache/2.0.63 (Unix)
```

so how can i start the installation of mod page speed module to speed up my wesite  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install mod page speed on whm not on domain name allotted cpanel.

*** Download putty for ssh connection to install page speed module.

*** Open putty.exe

*** Enter your Host Name like example.com

*** Port No 22 and click open

*** login as root

*** Enter Password (If you get Access denied error do not woory)  lets login with other user name which you use to login in cpanel

**** After login with othe user name Run the command "  su -  ".

**** Then Type your Root Password .

Follow the instruction from bellow command or link.

1) command:-

mod_pagespeed module for CPanel WHM

A custom module for CPanel WHM using CPanel Easy Framework - allows easy installation of mod_pagespeed via /scripts/easyapache on command line or through easyapache from WHM web console.
Installation instructions

```
Clone the installation scripts onto your CPanel server:

1) /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git clone https://github.com/pagespeed/cpanel.git  /tmp/pagespeed/

**Create Speed.pm.tar.gz**

 2)cd /tmp/pagespeed/Easy
 3)tar -zcvf Speed.pm.tar.gz pagespeed
 4)mkdir -p /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel/Easy
 5)mv Speed.pm Speed.pm.tar.gz -t /var/cpanel/easy/apache/custom_opt_mods/Cpanel/Easy/
 6)cd && rm -rf /tmp/pagespeed
Login into your cPanel WHM > EasyApache and look for "mod_pagespeed" option. Alternatively, you can run the easyapache installer from command line (/scripts/easyapache). Rebuild the Apache server, reboot it, and you're good to go!
```

Configuring mod_pagespeed

The installation script will copy a default pagespeed.conf file into /usr/local/apache/conf/ on your server. Please consult the following pages to customize your configuration:

```
mod_pagespeed module configuration
configuring mod_pagespeed filters
```

2) link:- http://www.prajith.in/update-mod_pagespeed/

after installation run bellow command.

Run command "  httpd -M   " will tell you page speed installed or not.

Now you have installed Mod page speed module on whm.